# Converting array of bytes to the hex string representation

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make the `hexStr` function faster?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string hexStr(unsigned char* data, int len)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex;
    for(int i=0;i<len;++i)
        ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)data[i];
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
   std::string packet = "";
   packet += 0x6b;
   packet += 0x0f;
   std::string hex = hexStr((unsigned char*)packet.c_str(), packet.length());
   printf("%s\n", hex.c_str()); // 6b0f
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, but I doubt you'll see any practical difference with such short input.

Two ideas: reduce the number of possible dynamic allocations, and do the conversion yourself with a small lookup table.

You can do both of these by pre-allocating the string container (you know the target size already), then doing the hex conversion manually. Something like this:

```
constexpr char hexmap[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                           '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

std::string hexStr(unsigned char *data, int len)
{
  std::string s(len * 2, ' ');
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    s[2 * i]     = hexmap[(data[i] & 0xF0) >> 4];
    s[2 * i + 1] = hexmap[data[i] & 0x0F];
  }
  return s;
}
```

Running this on my machine, with a test string that is 128k times 256 chars (from 0 to 255) gives me about 1.1s for your code, and about 0.18s for mine (redirecting to `/dev/null` to avoid I/O issues).

This *should* be at least not-worse than your version for small strings - there's no opportunity for the compiler to make a sub-optimal inlining decision on the string stream operators in particular, and (named) RVO will take care of eliding the copy from the return value to the caller's `std::string hex`.

Small benchmark to test this on (bad quality) pseudo-random 300 char long strings:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

std::string hexStr(unsigned char *data, int len)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::hex;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)data[i];
  return ss.str();
}

constexpr char hexmap[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                           '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

std::string hexStr2(unsigned char *data, int len)
{
  std::string s(len * 2, ' ');
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    s[2 * i]     = hexmap[(data[i] & 0xF0) >> 4];
    s[2 * i + 1] = hexmap[data[i] & 0x0F];
  }
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  std::vector<std::string> data;

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    std::string packet;
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
      packet += static_cast<char>(rand() % 256);
    data.push_back(packet);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    clock_t beg = clock();
    for (auto const &s : data) {
      std::string hex = hexStr((unsigned char *)s.c_str(), s.length());
      printf("%s\n", hex.c_str());
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Elapsed 1: %f\n",
            (clock() - beg) / (1.0 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    beg = clock();
    for (auto const &s : data) {
      std::string hex2 = hexStr2((unsigned char *)s.c_str(), s.length());
      printf("%s\n", hex2.c_str());
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Elapsed 2: %f\n",
            (clock() - beg) / (1.0 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
  }
}
```

Sample output compiled with clang++ (3.5) `-std=c++11 -O3` (doesn't vary too much), stdout redirected to `/dev/null`:

```
Elapsed 1: 0.018132
Elapsed 2: 0.001365
Elapsed 1: 0.017858
Elapsed 2: 0.001373
Elapsed 1: 0.018429
Elapsed 2: 0.001313
Elapsed 1: 0.018918
Elapsed 2: 0.001229
Elapsed 1: 0.019134
Elapsed 2: 0.001244
Elapsed 1: 0.018915
Elapsed 2: 0.001239
Elapsed 1: 0.018031
Elapsed 2: 0.001266
Elapsed 1: 0.018051
Elapsed 2: 0.001239
Elapsed 1: 0.017071
Elapsed 2: 0.001315
Elapsed 1: 0.017841
Elapsed 2: 0.001239
```

Comment: The real world packets are on average 300 bytes long and I have to convert nearly 1000 of them per second.

Comment: Added a small benchmark with that size of stings, looks ok. If this is really hot, you might want to try with a larger lookup table (256 `uint16_t`s) to do each char conversion in one operation. Larger data cache footprint, but fewer lookups. But benchmark that on your target CPU & compiler, possibly getting close to noise compared to the string allocation.

Comment: Your benchmark is great! I really appreciate the effort you put on this!